# jquery ordered list index

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add a click event to the numbered index of an ordered list with jQuery?
How?

Thanks

/*edit*/
well, maybe i wasn't clear enough, but i did specified that the event would have to be on the INDEX and not on the LI itself. I already have events attached to the LI, i want to know if there is a way to manipulate just the index.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#targetid').click(function(){'EVENT STUFF HERE'});
```

should do the trick, though if you're asking how to make the numbers in the list clickable your best bet would probably be to use CSS to extend a transparent DIV wrapped in an A tag back to the left and over the number.  Something like

```
margin-left: -30px; padding-left: 30px;
```

should let you do that without mucking up your list contents too bad.

Comment: it's a bit more complicated than that, i would like to on hover, turn the number into an X so when i clicked it it would delete the li, and it has to be only over the number cause i'm using another click event to the content

Comment: None of that was specified in the scope of your original question, Andre.  Look into jQuery's destroy() and html() methods.

Comment: i'm sorry kerin, but it was. I did specify that i wanted the click event on the index, not on the LI. I just edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: you didn't specify anything about turning the number into an X and deleting the <li>, brah.  I'm pretty sure that what you're asking can't be done with an ordered list because the numbers aren't represented in HTML.  You're going to have to use an unstyled, unordered list and manage the numbers yourself.

Comment: ok, that was what i wanted to know. without meaning to get into a flamewar, i don't think i needed to specify what i wanted to do with it, only what i needed to be done, and that i did. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [:nth-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to attach the event handler. E.g.

```
var index = 2;
$("ul li:nth-child(" + index + ")").click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thank you daff, i seem to not have been clear with my question. I just edited it. thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("ol li:eq(n)").click(function () {});
```

Comment: thank you kgiannakakis, i seem to not have been clear with my question. I just edited it. thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
$("ol li").click(function(e){});
```

Comment: thank you Naveed, i seem to not have been clear with my question. I just edited it. thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for how you can efficiently manage hovers with a class toggle:
http://pastie.org/805428

With that pattern you can just manage hiding of elements within your `li`s.